# I am surprised that he did/should do/should have done it

Tags: should

1 What is the difference between these:

1. I am surprised that he did it yesterday.
2. I am surprised that he should do it yesterday.
3. I am surprised that he should have done it yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

The first implies that I am sure that he actually did it yesterday.

The third implies that I have reason to think he did it, but I am not certain: perhaps I have heard that he did it.

The second does not seem natural to me, but I would take it to mean the same as the third.

This is a (comparatively rare) instance of English encoding [evidentiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidentiality)

Comment: To my ears, Colin, 'I am surprised that he should have done it yesterday' is a literary Edwardian  variant on 'I am surprised that he did it yesterday' (but I've not read much Edwardian literature for quite a while).